# Iterate through list of dictionaries and print message

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that looks similar to following:

```
points = [
{"callsign": "A001", "daily_points":10, "number":"+447774076621"},
{"callsign": "A002", "daily_points":5, "number":"+447958708481"}
]
```

I am trying to iterate through list to print message like:
"Hi A001 you received 10 points today"

I have tried using following code:

```
for callsign, daily_points in points.items():
print(f"Hi {callsign} you recieved {daily_points} points today.")
```

But it returns: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: items is a method of dictionary, and points is a list of dictionaries

Answer (score 5):

`points` is a list, not a dictionary. You have to loop through each element in the list, then read the dictionary. The code looks somehow like this:

```py
for point in points:
    print(f"Hi {point['callsign']} you received {point['daily_points']} points today.")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.format`:

```
for point in points:
    print("Hi {callsign} you recieved {daily_points} points today.".format(**point))
```

Also since in python 3.6+ dict's preserve order you can keep most your code just replace `points.items()` with `map(dict.values, points)`:

```
for callsign, daily_points, *_ in map(dict.values, points):
    print(f"Hi {callsign} you recieved {daily_points} points today.")
```

Comment: what does `*_` do? if it is ok to ask qustions in comments

Comment: It's [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

Comment: not too sure, but I would assume because the first example doesn't seem to compile

Comment: @rv.kvetch I corrected it not compiling. I was missing a asterisk.

Comment: [`itemgetter("callsign", "daily_points")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) looks slightly better and doesn't rely on order. (that's actually what `str.format()` does internally when you pass keyword arguments)

Answer (score 1):

The variable 'points' is a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary itself.
To loop over each dictionary in the list, you could:

```py
points = [
{"callsign": "A001", "daily_points":10, "number":"+447774076621"},
{"callsign": "A002", "daily_points":5, "number":"+447958708481"}
]

for point in points:
    print(f"Hi {point['callsign']} you recieved {point['daily_points']} points today.")
```

This would iterate through the list, and print out the information in each dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
for point in points:
    callsign, daily_points, number = point['callsign'], point['daily_points'], point['number']
    print(f"Hi {callsign} you recieved {daily_points} points today.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through every record in `points` and do this.

```
for i in range(len(points)):
    print(f"Hi {points[i]['callsign']} you recieved {points[i]['daily_points']} points today.")
```

**Output**

```
Hi A001 you recieved 10 points today.
Hi A002 you recieved 5 points today.
```

Comment: It works, but range(len) is unnecessary

Comment: Why not just iterate over each dictionary, like `for d in points`? that way you wouldn't need the `points[i]`

Comment: I usually prefer loops over a range. Your suggestion would be the better choice in this case though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are iterating over `points`, that is a list and has no `items` attribute.

One approach is to use [`.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and pass the dictionary directly:

```
points = [
    {"callsign": "A001", "daily_points": 10, "number": "+447774076621"},
    {"callsign": "A002", "daily_points": 5, "number": "+447958708481"}
]

for d in points:
    print("Hi {callsign} you received {daily_points} points today.".format(**d))
```

**Output**

```
Hi A001 you received 10 points today.
Hi A002 you received 5 points today.
```

Comment: smart ...... ;)

Comment: what does `**d` do? Does the d stand for dicionary? And would only one asterix mean that only the keys are used?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution looks like this:

```
for person in points:
    print(f"Hi {person['callsign']} you recieved {person['daily_points']} points today.")
```

Your solution is wrong because list does not have method items(), and it can not unpack dictionary keys like that.

Answer (score 1):

you need to access the value with the key

```
for user in points:
    print(f"Hi {user['callsign']} you recieved {user['daily_points']} points today.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the items() method is for lists only, not for dictionaries. However, you could try something like this:

```
for dictionary in points:
    print(f"Hi {dictionary['callsign']} you recieved {dictionary['daily_points']} points today.")
```

Or you can use the get() method as follows:

```
for dictionary in points:
    print(f"Hi {dictionary.get('callsign')} you recieved {dictionary.get('daily_points')} points today.")
```

Answer (score -1):

You mix dict and list..

See below

```
points = [{
    "callsign": "A001",
    "daily_points": 10,
    "number": "+447774076621"
}, {
    "callsign": "A002",
    "daily_points": 5,
    "number": "+447958708481"
}]

for point in points:
    print(
        f'Hi {point.get("callsign")} you received {point.get("daily_points")} points today.'
    )
```

output

```
Hi A001 you received 10 points today.
Hi A002 you received 5 points today.
```